# Kivy error: NameError 'Clock' is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

I am picking up Kivy and stuck on the titled error. I am simply trying to run a function 1 min after the app started:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App

class ScreamApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.wakemeup, 60)

    def wakemeup(self, nap):
        #vibrate here
    pass



if __name__=="__main__":
    ScreamApp().run()
```

When I run it, it says:

NameError: name 'Clock' is not defined. It is a built in class, according to the documentation. What am i mmissing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to import `Clock` before using it. Put this at the top:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

I guess you copy/pasted that from an example on their documentation. For the sake of brevity, many examples leave out the imports at the start, so you need to figure our the imports yourself.